# Convertir la posicion de un substring "x" en un valor posicional?

Tags: c#, operador, substring

Vereis, tratando de desarrollar en C# un método que lea una operación introducida por el usuario me he encontrado un pequeño problema.

Ya tengo el planteamiento del programa terminado, en la teoría y si no me he equivocado debería funcionar a la perfeccion tal y como esta escrito.

El problema me llega a la hora de guardar el valor de la posición de un substring en una variable para luego en otro substring poder llegar hasta ese valor.

Dejo por aqui el extracto del código con el que me interesaría que me echeis una mano.

```
string operacion;
        int longitud;
        string[] primerNumSTR = new string[3];
        double[] primerNum = new double[3];
        string[] segundoNumSTR = new string[3];
        double[] segundoNum = new double[3];
        string operador;


        Console.WriteLine("Introduce una operacion.");
        operacion = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        longitud = operacion.Length;
        //operacion.Substring(0, longitud);


        for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
        {
            string digito = operacion.Substring(i, 1);






            if (Char.IsDigit(Convert.ToChar(digito)))
            {


            }
            else
            {

                operador = digito;

                if (operador == "x")
                {
                    int posicion = 
                    primerNumSTR[0] = operacion.Substring(0, operador);
                    primerNum[0] = primerNumSTR.Length;
                    segundoNumSTR[0] = operacion.Substring(operacion.Substring("x", operacion.Length));
                    segundoNum[0] = segundoNumSTR.Length;
                    double multi = primerNum[0] * segundoNum[0];
                    Console.WriteLine(multi);

                }
                else if (operador == "-")
                {
                    primerNumSTR[1] = operacion.Substring(0, operador.IndexOf("-"));
                }
                else if (operador == "+")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Tu operacion es una suma");
                    primerNumSTR[2] = operacion.Substring(0, operador.IndexOf("+"));

                }
                else if (operador == "/")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Tu operacion es una division");
                    primerNumSTR[3] = operacion.Substring(0, operador.IndexOf("/"));

                }
            }

        }
```

Lo que trato de hacer es reemplazar la cadena "x" por un valor posicional, ya que si no lo hago me devuelve el error Argumento 1: No se puede convertir de string a int.

Creo que es una duda un poco de novato, pero realmente y tras estar toda la tarde dándole vueltas al asunto, no he llegado a la conclusión de cómo solucionarlo.

Comment: de donde vas a obtener el "valor posicional" ?

Comment: Disculpa, no he tenido en cuenta que yo daba por hecho de donde, pero vosotros no lo veis.
A ver si ahora puedes ayudarme y gracias.

Comment: Por lo que logro entender de tu pregunta, deseas obtener la posición de un carácter que indica una operación (matemática supongo). La misma viene en forma de `String`, por ejemplo: `"23x15"`. Deseas la posición del carácter `x`, aunque realmente no creo que necesites dicho dato. Sin embargo, si es lo que requieres, puedes usar el método `IndexOf()` del tipo `String`. Algo como `int posicion = operacion.IndexOf("x");`. Si el valor devuelto por `IndexOf` es `-1`, significa que `x` no fue encontrado en la cadena. Igual @LeandroTuttini es el experto aqui y yo me hago a un lado. XD

Comment: Si vas a iterar cada char de la cadena recuerda que un string es basicamente un char[], por lo tanto esto `for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)` lo puedes cambiar por esto `foreach(char digito in operacion)`, no necesitas usar ningun `substring()`

Comment: Una duda si quieres parsear una formula no te conviene usar una libreria matematica? hay muchas que ejecutaran la expresion y obtendras el resultado

Comment: @Mauricio Contreras En efecto, era justo lo que buscaba. No se como no se me ha ocurrido antes. Supongo que aún estoy muy verde en esto de la programación.
Leandro, hasta el momento solo he llegado hasta los bucles for por lo que aún no sé las funciones del foreach ni se invocar a librerías. Te recuerdo que apenas es mi cuarto dia en C# por lo que tampoco quiero adelantarme a conceptos más avanzados sin antes haberme quedado claro lo que he visto hasta ahora. De todas maneras muchas gracias por las sugerencias, investigaré un poco sobre lo que me has dicho.